# ImageDataGenerator and fit_generator in Keras: understanding epochs

Tags: keras

I am trying to understand how the data generator in Keras is used during training. If have a setup such as

```python
datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
datagen.fit(x_train)
model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, x_test, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=100,
                    epochs=20)
```

How can I get a sense for how much data is being "generated", and when? I'm having trouble understand how `batch_size` and `steps_per_epoch` are related.

Is the above equivalent to something like

```python
for epoch 1 to 20:
    for each img in x_train:
        generate 100 morphed images based on img
        put these into batches of size 32
        fit each batch
```

Alternatively, maybe it works like this:

```python
for epoch 1 to 20:
    for each img in x_train:
        generate 100 morphed images based on img
    put all of the 100*x_train.shape[0] images into batches of size 32
    fit each batch
```

So how does this work exactly?
Is there a way to investigate/debug this?

Answer (score 0):

It works like:

```
for epoch in range(20):
    for step in range(steps_per_epoch):
       yield x,y     
       #where x.shape = (32,imgshape1,imgshape2,imgshape3)
       #where y.shape = (32,your_output_shape....)
```

To see exactly how the generator is creating batches (which I suspect is altered img1, altered img2, altered img3..., with possible shuffling), you can:

```
gen = datagen.flow(x_train, x_test, batch_size=32)

for i in range(2*your_total_images):
    x,y = next(gen) #gets a batch
    useAPlottingLibraryAndPlot(x) #where x contains 32 images
```